# work by Apache and port 80

Tags: sql-server, apache, port80

Later, I worked by apache and I didn't any problem, but after install SQL Server 2008, apache don't work.
I think there is problem on port 80.

Comment: What have you tried?

1. Is apache even running in the first place?
2. What do you see when you type "localhost" in the address bar?

Answer (score 2):

My SQL Processes usually take port 80 but im not sure how to change which port MY SQL uses.
What do you see when you type `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` or your computer's local ip in your web browser?

To find which app is using Port 80 go on Command Prompt and type:

```
netstat -aon
```

Scroll up till you see some thing like:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80              LISTENING       ####
```

In the part that says *####*, there will be a number!

Take note of that number and open Task Manager and go i=on services and look for that number under the "PID" tab. In my case it was 2264, so I'd look for 2264. When you find it there it tells you, but if it doesn't (like it says PID=4), you might have IIS on. So go to

**Control Panel** >> **Administrative Tools** >> **Component Services** >> **Services (Local)** and find ***Web Deployment Agent Service***

Stop that service. Also, find World Wide Web Publishing Service and stop that...

Comment: Here, the PID is 7420, but it doesn't appear on services. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

it may be because of the port 80 occupied by the SQL Server 2008. you can try to see if the it is occupied by SQL Server 2008 using `netstat`  command if so then you can change the configuration either of apache or SQL Server 2008 and configure any of to a new port.

see [how to change the port in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- see if the process is up running.
- look the apache log
- doubt its SQL taking port 80. You can find out by using command netstat to find out all the listening ports

Let's identify the issue first