# XAMPP Port 80 Error In Windows 7

Tags: xampp, port80

XAMPP 3.1.0 isn't working because port 80 is in use. I've looked around and this seems to be a common problem. I've stopped IIS, skype isn't running, web deployment agent service is running, I've changed the configuration of Apache's httpd.conf to listen to port 80 as per the second answer to this question: [XAMPP PORT 80 is Busy / EasyPHP error in Apache configuration file:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103924/xampp-port-80-is-busy-easyphp-error-in-apache-configuration-file) but still no luck. Here are the error messages in XAMPP's control panel:

```
2:03:49 PM [Apache] Problem detected!
2:03:49 PM [Apache] Port 80 in use by "system"!
2:03:49 PM [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:03:49 PM [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:03:49 PM [Apache] or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
2:03:49 PM [Apache] XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  MySQL Service detected with wrong path
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Change XAMPP MySQL settings or
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Problem detected!
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by "mysqld.exe"!
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:03:49 PM [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL to listen on a different port
2:03:49 PM [Tomcat] Problem detected!
2:03:49 PM [Tomcat] Port 8080 in use by "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
2:03:49 PM [Tomcat] Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:03:49 PM [Tomcat] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:03:49 PM [Tomcat] or reconfigure Tomcat to listen on a different port
```

When I go to localhost it takes me to the IIS7 screen even though the service is stopped in control panel.

Answer (score 6):

Use `netstat -bano` in an elevated command prompt to see what apps are listening on which ports.

But usually, the following applications use port 80 in Windows:

```
IIS
World Wide Web Publishing service
IIS Admin Service
SQL Server Reporting services
Web Deployment Agent Service
```

Stop any of the above applications that are running. You can do this on the Services tab in Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer by The Computer Hugger on this link (I hope it helps)
[work by Apache and port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722447/work-by-apache-and-port-80?answertab=active#tab-top)

If not then try following because it helped in my case:
The Reason for error is that an SQL Reporting services is utilizing the PORT 80 that Apache Uses. Disabling the SQL Reporting Services to start automatically will definitely solve the Problem.

Stopping SQL Reporting Service, Start, then type Administrative Tools, click on the name , select computer Management, then Services and applications> SQL Server Configuration> Services & Look for SQL Reporting Servicves, Set it to Manual start, and stop.

Restart Your XAMPP Server and hopefully you are good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

**I got this error after installing XAMPP on Windows 8 as well:**

```
[Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Apache]    or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
```

**This is what I did to fix it:**

1. Go to Windows Update and make sure all windows updates have been processed.
2. Restart the computer.  And start the XAMPP control panel.  Then the errors are gone and displays this:

   ```
   [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8 Pro  64-bit
   [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
   [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
   [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
   [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
   [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
   [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
   [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
   [main]  Checking for prerequisites
   [main]  All prerequisites found
   [main]  Initializing Modules
   [main]  Starting Check-Timer
   [main]  Control Panel Ready
   ```

So a few warnings, but it started up OK.